# How to use directives for multiple form elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to check if an input is katakana characters or not.

This code works for one element :

```
var KANA_FULL_SIZE_REGEXP = /^([ァ-ン。、ー「」．\s]+)$/;
var KANA_HAFL_SIZE_REGEXP = /^([ｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ｡｢｣､･ｰ\s]+)$/;
var KANA_ALL_SIZE_REGEXP = /^([ァ-ンｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ｡`-｢｣．。､ー「」･\s]+)$/;

 app.directive('kataKana', function() {
    return {
        // restrict: 'A',
        // scope: {},
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            if(!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }

            if (ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty(element.val())) {
               scope.kanaerror = false;
            }

            element.bind('keypress', function(event) {

                if(event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
            /**
             * var setObjFill 
             *     setObjFill == 0 check katakana full size and half size
             *     setObjFill == 1 check katakana only full size
             *     setObjFill == 2 check katakana only half size  
             */
            element.bind('keyup', function(event) {
                if (!element.val() || element.val() == null || element.val() == '') {
                    scope.kanaerror = false;
                } else {
                    var setObjFill = attrs.kataKana.split(',');
                    if(setObjFill == 0) {
                        if (KANA_ALL_SIZE_REGEXP.test(element.val())) {
                            scope.kanaerror = false;
                        } else {
                            scope.kanaerror = true;
                        }
                    }　else if (setObjFill == 1) {
                        console.log('ee');
                        if (KANA_FULL_SIZE_REGEXP.test(element.val())) {
                            scope.kanaerror = false;
                        } else {
                            scope.kanaerror = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (KANA_HAFL_SIZE_REGEXP.test(element.val())) {
                            scope.kanaerror = false;
                        } else {
                            scope.kanaerror = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
 });
```

in html:

```
<input id="txt_kana" kata-kana="1" name="txt_kana">
```

### The problem

If in that form we use `kata-kana="1"` twice, my code always return `true` or `false` for two elements using `kata-kana="1"`. Because my code return `scope.kanaerror`. But I don't know how to resolve that problem.

Comment: try with changing a custom attribute of the input element in place of returning scope.kanaerror . Set the value of the custom attribute based on the result of regex.

Comment: Sometime, I has try `var nameForm = element.attr('name')` and set `scope.formEdit.nameForm = false;` but that's syntax return error besause it's not understand `nameForm` stay here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is return `true` or `false` not `scope`. And it's working.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

    if(!ngModelCtrl) {
        return;
    }
    /**
     * var setObjFill 
     *     setObjFill == 0 check katakana full size and half size
     *     setObjFill == 1 check katakana only full size
     *     setObjFill == 2 check katakana only half size  
     */
    ngModelCtrl.$validators.katakana = function(model, value) {
        if (value == '' || value == undefined){
            return true;
        }
        var setObjFill = attrs.kataKana.split(',');
        if (setObjFill == 0) {
            var test = KANA_ALL_SIZE_REGEXP.test(value);
        }　else if (setObjFill == 1) {
            var test = KANA_FULL_SIZE_REGEXP.test(value);
        } else {
            var test = KANA_HAFL_SIZE_REGEXP.test(value);
        }
        return test;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to check if the input is Katakana japanese language by watching scope.kanaerror which is a share scope. if you have multiple inputs but your scope.kanaerror is only one, then scope is not issolated that why you always get true or false(i guess).

I suggest you use ng-model for your input and check the model itself for each input if you have them more than two.

```
<input id="txt_kana" ng-model='input1' kata-kana name="txt_kana">
<input id="txt_kana" ng-model='input2' kata-kana name="txt_kana">
```

And in your directive:

```
app.directive('kataKana', function() {
  return {
    // restrict: 'A',
    // scope: {},
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var KANA_ALL_SIZE_REGEXP = /\d+/g;
      var KANA_FULL_SIZE_REGEXP = /[A-Z]/g;
      var KANA_HAFL_SIZE_REGEXP = /[a-z]/g;


      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
        // this is to limit input charactor
        element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode === 5) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }
        });
        if (!viewValue) {
          return false; // return to modelValue for controller
        }
        if (KANA_ALL_SIZE_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          return 'helo'; // return to modelValue for controller and interpolation
        } else if (KANA_FULL_SIZE_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          return 'hi'; //return to modelValue for controller
        } else if (KANA_HAFL_SIZE_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          return 'hey'; //return to modelValue for controller
        }

      })
    }
  };
});
```

I refactor your code but as I cannot type japanese so I change Regex. I hope you get the idea. in my code I make use the `ngModelcontroler.$parsers` and `viewValue  to return modelValue` which use by controller and interpolation.  [Here is a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BPD4GFSc6khdsHicrGrF?p=preview).  hope that help.

Comment: Yep, my solution is follow syntax: `ngModelCtrl.$validators.katakana` and return `true` or `false` not return `scope`. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
// scope: {},
```

to

```
scope: true,
```

This will give each instance it's own scope that is inherited from the parent scope. At the moment they are all sharing the parent scope and when one attaches kanaerror to the scope it is on all.

Comment: It's not working. When I chang this, scope return  true. So result alway return true although input incorrectly or correctly.

Comment: return true? What do you mean return true, it is just a property set to true, there is no return true.

Comment: That's mean `scope.kanaerror` alway return `false`. The validate not working.